# Can $2f(x)\leq f(2x)$ imply $f(x)$ is convex?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f(x)$ be twice-differentiable over $(0,+\infty)$ and satisfy that:

1. $f(0)=0$;
2. $\forall x>0:2f(x)\leq f(2x)$.

Can we derive $f''(x)\geq 0$? Namely, can we derive $f(x)$ is convex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even for nonnegative functions, this isn't true. Consider
$$
x^2\left(1-\cos(2\pi\log_2x)\right)
$$
(with $f(0)=0$). Then we have
$$
f(2x)=4f(x)\geq 2f(x)
$$
yet the function is not convex at all.

Comment: Thanks for your counterexample！

Answer (score 4):

No, $f$ is not necessarily convex. Counterexamples can be constructed as follows: First define $f$ on the interval $[1, 2]$ with the following properties:

- $2f(1) =  f(2)$,
- $f'(1) = f'(2)$,
- $f''(1) = f''(2) = 0$,
- $f$ is not convex on $[1, 2]$.

(A possible choice is $f(x) = x + \sin^2( 2 \pi x)$ for $1 \le x \le 2$).

Then extend the domain of $f$ to $(0, \infty)$ by defining
$$
 f(x) = 2^{-n} f(2^n x)
$$
where $n \in \Bbb Z$ is chosen such that $2^n x \in [1,2]$. Finally set $f(0) = 0$.

Then $f$ is twice differentiable,  $2f(x) = f(2x)$ for all $x \ge 0$, but $f$ is  not convex.